# How do you run micronaut from gradle with local properties

Tags: gradle, micronaut

I want to run Micronaut server from Gradle command line with "local" environment variables.
The regular command

```
.\gradlew.bat run
```

will use default variables defined in application.yml file.
I want to override some of them with values for my local environment and therefore need to specify system property *micronaut.environments=local* to use overriding values from *application-local.yml* file.

```
.\gradlew.bat run -Dmicronaut.environments=local
```

The command above won't work as Gradle will take only *-Dmicronaut* for the system property and the rest ".environments=local" will be considered as another task name:

```
Task '.environments=local' not found in root project 'abc'
```

What would be the correct way to pass such system property to the java process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Command below works for **unix**, probably it should work also for **windows**:

```sh
MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=local gradle run
```

or use *gradle wrapper*

```sh
MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=local .\gradlew.bat run
```

P.S. also, you can find the same approach for [Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/832#issuecomment-133830293)

Comment: Thanks, that was it, totally overlooked this approach, thought I have to define the variable with the gradle command itself.

Comment: This also works in IntelliJ by specifing "environment variables" in the run configuration like "MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS=local"

Answer (score 3):

My approach is to add a gradle task.

```
task runLocal(type: JavaExec) {
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
   main = "dontdrive.Application"
   jvmArgs '-Dmicronaut.environments=local'
}
```

then start with:

```
./gradlew runLocal
```